# To create a vector of x in the form: $x_0 = 0$ and $x_n=1$ , $x_k=x_{k-1}+2^{-k}$

Tags: matlab

Here is my code, the output I get is when use N=4 is [0,0,0,1], does anyone knows where the problem is?
Thanks

```
function xg = GenMesh(N)
    xg=[];
    xg(1) = 0;
    for i=2:length(N)-1
        xg(i)=xg(i-1)+2.^(-i);
    end
    xg(N)=1;
end
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the code into the question, images of code are more than useless.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's my first time to ask a question, I will remember thiis

Comment: This is not just advice for the next question, it is a request for you to [edit] this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in the upper limit of your `for` loop: you assign `length(N)` to it, but `N` is a scalar, so its `length=1`. You have to directly set `N` as upper limit.

Also, you should initialise the size of `xg` to `N` before operating on it, otherwise the MATLAB interpreter will have to keep expanding its size throughout the loop.

Here below is a working version of your function:

```
function xg = GenMesh(N)
    xg = zeros(1,N);                % set dimension and initialise to 0

    for i = 2:N-1                   % N not length(N)
        xg(i) = xg(i-1) + 2^(-i);   % normal ^, not .^
    end

    xg(N)=1;
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreicate it. :)

Comment: @hehex4 great, could you also upvote this answer if it solved your problem? Many thanks